# Virtualbox Androidx86 on OSX El Capitan

Tags: bluetooth, virtualbox, osx-elcapitan, android-x86

I have a need to set up an additional android device with Bluetooth so I attempted to install Android-86 4.4r5 in VirtualBox on OSX el Capitan; however, for some odd reason I can't get the bluetooth to work. I set up the bluetooth the same way you would for any other OS (even though I haven't run another os in virtualbox on my mbp) i.e. enable serial port then enable usb devices check usb2.0 and filter the correct bluetooth device. Which actually comes up automatically in a list a lot easier than before. I originally figured that even though I don't use bluetooth that it could be a user process and attempted to end all user processes with:

`sudo killall -u $(whoami) cfprefsd`

When that didn't work I attempted to use:

`launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist`

in combination with `kextstat | grep -i "blue"` and kextunload for each of the modules shown which essential results in:

```
kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily
kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager
```

However for some odd reason each each give me an early termination error that their are processes using it.

Any assistance would be very helpful.

Off topic: I decided to try Remix OS the 32 bit version instead of the 64 bit which is android based and very experimental with paravirtualization set to Legacy. It seems the bluetooth works in Remix OS fine; however, their is horrible input lag and startup takes a long time which can be an issue for random demonstrations.